# G-Sheets COUNT cells and show empty cell on 0

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently trying to count tickets of a specific type in Google Sheets and visualise them through a Combo Chart. It is no big deal, but bugging me for the clean look of the dashboard.

For MEDIAN Durations I use `=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(MEDIAN(IF((Incidents!$L:$L="Yes")*(Incidents!$N:$N=$A38);Incidents!$P:$P))))` and IFERROR automatically leaves the cell empty on default.

If I do the same with
`=IFERROR(COUNTIFS(Incidents!$L:$L;"Yes";Incidents!$N:$N;$A38;Incidents!$C:$C;"Yes"))`
the result will be occasionally 0 in the past or always in the future of course.

When I now try to show both values in a Combo Chart, I show the MEDIAN as Stepped Area and the COUNT as Column. The MEDIAN shows nothing with labeles enabled. COUNT will show the 0 when the labels are enabled.

I tried to hide the 0 with an IF function, checking first if the result is 0 or not. If not, do the calc normally, if yes show " ". But that will then break my chart and the Incidents do not appear as a Series anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the problem. Checking with IF, if there is a 0 or not but instead of " " on FALSE I use "" to return a BLANK cell. Silly me.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(Incidents!$L:$L;"Yes";Incidents!$N:$N;$A37;Incidents!$C:$C;"Yes")<>0;COUNTIFS(Incidents!$L:$L;"Yes";Incidents!$N:$N;$A37;Incidents!$C:$C;"Yes");"")`